# divided pdf in two

Tags: python, latex, pdflatex

I need a program to divide a each PDF page in two (left,right). So I made this code, but for some reason it doesn't catch the image for the title. When trying with other books it didn't work either.

```
import os

#Info that i collect to know the numbers of pages and the pdf file name
number = int(input("Number os pages: " ))
file = input("Name of the file: " )
file = str(file) + ".pdf"


text = open("for_the_latex.txt","w")

#Putting the first part of the latex document

a =  "\documentclass{article}" + "\n" 
b =  "\\usepackage{pdfpages}" + "\n"
c =  "\\begin{document}"

text.write(a)
text.write(b)
text.write(c)

#This is the core of the program
#It basically write in a text document to include the pdf for each page

for i in range(1,number +1): 
    a = "\includepdf[pages=" + str( i) + ",trim=0 0 400 0]{" + file + "}" + "\n"
    text.write(a)


#Writing the finish part
quatro = "\end{document}"

text.write(quatro)

text.close()

#renaming to .tex
os.rename("for_the_latex.txt", "divided.tex")

#activating the latex
os.system("pdflatex divided.tex")
```

where is the error ?

[image]

I want to divide the PDF in two.

Comment: What does "it don't catch the image for the title" mean? And why don't you use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)?

Comment: please can you show an image of the what the code does (split in half pdf)

Comment: (Why doesn't the Low Quality Question Filter catch `hi` at the start of a post anymore?)

Comment: I didn't know about argparse. Thanks for showing me.  I mean split each pdf page in two

Comment: I still don't know, what your exact problem is, can you include your error message or your wrong output? If it is urgent, you should check out the program `gscan2pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following minimal document (called `example-document.pdf`) that contains 6 pages, each exactly split in half by colour and number:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

% http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-a4-numbered.pdf
\includepdf[pages={1-2},nup=2]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={3-4},nup=2]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={5-6},nup=2]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={7-8},nup=2]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={9-10},nup=2]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={11-12},nup=2]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to split these back into a 12-page document. Here's the code for LaTeX:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages,pgffor}

\newlength{\pagedim}% To store page dimensions, if necessary

\begin{document}

\foreach \docpage in {1,...,6} {
  \settowidth{\pagedim}{\includegraphics[page=\docpage]{example-document.pdf}}% Establish page width
  \includepdf[pages={\docpage},trim=0 0 .5\pagedim{} 0,clip]{example-document.pdf}% Left half
  \includepdf[pages={\docpage},trim=.5\pagedim{} 0 0 0,clip]{example-document.pdf}% Right half
}

\end{document}
```

It's not necessary to read in every page and establish its width (stored in `\pagedim`), but I wasn't sure whether your pages may have differing sizes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, I'm not quite sure, if I understand your problem correctly. Since I can execute your program and it includes only the left part of the initial document, I modified the code a bit.

```
import os

#Info that i collect to know the numbers of pages and the pdf file name
number = int(input("Number of pages: "))
file = input("Name of the file: ")
file = str(file) + ".pdf"

text = open("divided.tex","w")

#Putting the first part of the latex document
header ='''
\\documentclass{article}
\\usepackage{pdfpages}
\\begin{document}
'''

#This is the core of the program
#It basically write in a text document to include the pdf for each page

middle=''
for i in range(1,number +1):
    middle += "\includepdf[pages={},trim=0 0 400 0]{{{}}}\n".format(i, file)
    middle += "\includepdf[pages={},trim=400 0 0 0]{{{}}}\n".format(i, file)

#Writing the finish part
quatro = "\end{document}"

text.write(header)
text.write(middle)
text.write(quatro)
text.close()

#activating the latex
os.system("pdflatex divided.tex")
```